# Let $K = k(x_1 ,...,x_n )$ be the field of rational functions in $n$ variables over a field $k$. Show that the definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

**Let $K = k(x_1 ,...,x_n )$ be the field of rational functions in $n$ variables
over a field $k$. Show that the definition
$\sigma (\frac{f(x_1,...,x_n)}{g(x_1,...,x_n)})=\frac{f(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})}{g(x_{\sigma(1)},...,x_{\sigma(n)})}$ 
makes a permutation $\sigma \in S_n$ into a field automorphism of K.**

I am using the following exercise to demonstrate this but I do not know if I can use it:

*Let $B$ be an integral domain with quotient field $F$. If $\varphi :B\rightarrow B$ is a ring automorphism, show that $\varphi$ induces a ring automorphism
$\varphi' :F\rightarrow F$ defined by $\varphi '(\frac{a}{b})=\frac{\varphi (a)}{\varphi(b) }$ if $a,b\in B$ with $b\neq 0$.*

Define $\sigma ':k[x_1,...,x_2]\rightarrow k[x_1,...,x_2]$ by  $\sigma' (f(x_1,...,x_n))=f(x_{\sigma'(1)},...,x_{\sigma'(n)})$, then by the previous problem there is that sigma and it is a field automorphism.

Is this test okay? Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes! By the way, it's $k[x_1, \cdots, x_n]$, a small typo. You have to check that $\sigma'$ is an automorphism.

Comment: Agree with Krish. Hint for the task: Show that $(\sigma^{-1})'$ is the inverse of $\sigma'$.